# Azure Search FilterOn Linq Not Working

Tags: azure-search

I am running Sitecore 9 update 2 on Azure Web App, with Azure Search. I am trying to use the Sitecore Facet Support, that works completely fine with Solr, but having no luck at all with Azure.

So my scenario is I am trying to build filters on the search results page and based on the Sitecore [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/support-reference-for-azure-search.html)

[image]

My code (fine with Solr) looks like this:

```
    queryable = queryable.FacetOn(item => item[facet.FieldName]);
```

So **facet.FieldName** would in my case be "content_type" that I would be expecting Azure to return my a list of Categories for the filters.

So I am expecting (again fine with Solr) to allow me to follow up with something like this:

```
        foreach (var category in queryable.GetFacets().Categories)
        {
            //blah
        }
```

But the Facet Categories just don't get set. There's no errors in the logs, and doesn't effect the Search results. Based on what I have read and understood [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/linq-to-sitecore.html)  this should be working the same across the two different search providers.

[image]

Comment: Can you check the search logs? They should log the actual request. Compare the solr and azure version in those logs..

Comment: I can see in the the Search logs that the Solr version has facet info in the Query where as the Azure one doesn't have anything. The parameter &facet=true in the Solr one which could be the difference, but problem is how do explicitly say to add that in the Azure query or do I need to?